# Do we need separate [3ds] and [2ds] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merging

As stated in the [3ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3ds) tag excerpt:

> The Nintendo 3DS is a portable gaming console released by Nintendo in 2011. Use this tag for 3DS, 3DS XL, **2DS**, and the New 3DS XL

As you can see, it states that the [3ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3ds) tag should be used for questions regarding Nintendo 2DS's too, however we also have a [2ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2ds) too. Are both necessary? Or is the [2ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2ds) tag satisfactorily covered by the [3ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3ds) tag?

Comment: Given that, as you mentioned, the 2DS is already included as part of the [tag:3ds] tag, I don't see a reason to make a separate one.

Comment: @Yuuki - [tag:2ds] already exists, I think Crafter0800 means we should combine the two :-)

Comment: The only reason we might need separate ones if for hardware.

Answer (score 5):

The [2ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2ds) and [3ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3ds) tags can probably be merged.....BUUUT before we do, should we have a look at the way we're tagging the entire 3DS line of consoles? We do currently seem to have tags for most of the major console revisions:

- [3ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3ds)
- [3ds-xl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3ds-xl)
- [2ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2ds)
- [new-3ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-3ds)
- [new-3ds-xl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-3ds-xl)

According to the [Nintendo 3DS Product Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_3DS_family), the 2DS, 3DS and 3DS XL are substantially similar under the hood, the primary differences being form factor, battery life and the 2DS's removal of 3D functionality.

Likewise the 'New Nintendo 3DS' (including 2DS and XL variants) do offer improved performance and have [games that are exclusive](https://www.neogaf.com/threads/games-that-are-exclusive-enhanced-on-the-new-3ds.1177455/) to the improved versions, taking advantage of the better hardware. But just like the 'original' revision, all the 'New' revision consoles are substantially similar under the hood.

So my question is, if we're going to combine [2ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2ds) and [3ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3ds), should we not also consider the other console tags as well?

If combining is the way forward, I propose condensing these individual tags down to two tags, one for the 'OG' 3DS family, and one for the 'New' 3DS family. I'm open to suggestions about the potential names, but here's a couple of suggestions:

- [nintendo-3ds-family](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-3ds-family) or [nintendo-3ds-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-3ds-series) or [nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds)
- [new-nintendo-3ds-family](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-nintendo-3ds-family) or [new-nintendo-3ds-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-nintendo-3ds-series) or [new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl)

If this is something the community thinks is best, I'm happy to action these at some point.

Comment: Regarding the addition of 'Nintendo' to the tags - with the way SEO works on Arqade (the first tag on the question being added to the Navigation title of the page), having 'Nintendo' feature in the tag will only help SEO in the long run.

Comment: I was eventually going to create a tag rename request for adding `nintendo` as a prefix to match `nintendo-switch`, but now's a good a time as any to add that :-)

Comment: @Thunderforge Yeah. Do you have a preference for what the top level tag should be for the two 3DS families? Doesn't have to be one of the suggestions above if you have a better one :)

Comment: How do other communities (or Nintendo) usually refer to them? I don’t have a strong preference since I don’t use them, but I don’t think we need to go the Pokémon route and list them all (although perhaps as a synonym). Maybe `*-family` to distinguish from the `*-series` pattern we use for video game franchises?

Comment: I think there should be a tag for both because the hardware is different, not just the 3d capability. So if there's a questions like "How to remove SD card for new 3DS xL?" and "How to remove SD card for new 2DS" the answers will be different.

Comment: @Diriector_Doc is there any reason that couldn't be answered with "for 3DS do...  for 2DS do..." etc? Do you want to expand on that point into an answer here?